# Re-using Android's default click animation

Tags: android, animation, onclick

I've set up an ExpandableListView with clickable childs that change color when they're clicked on. I'd like to make it so instead of instantly changing the color, it changes with an animation.

I noticed that the default animation for clicking ELV (or any type of list, I suppose) is pretty cool (at least in my version of the OS): it expands with a kind of grey color covering the entire item for an instant before going back to the original color. The idea is using this animation to change the color of the clicked child, with an obvious difference: it wouldn't go back to it's original color. Is this too complicated?, if not then how can it be done?

If someone has information about animating a child color change please let me know as well.